# Codeigniter echo/var_dump not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Why doesn't var_dump work here, the ajax call is successful, but there is nothing printed, not even a string literal print from the PHP.

**My controller**

```
function check_links() {            
  $matches = $this->input->get('matchesJSON');        
  var_dump($matches);
  //$this->load->view('publish_links_view');
}
```

**Ajax call**

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  data: 'matchesJSON='+matchesJSON,
  url: 'publishlinks/check_links',
  success:                    
    function(response) {

    }
})
```

Comment: When using Ajax, use a tool like http://www.firephp.org/ to send logging messages to the client without messing up the response text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're expecting it to var_dump to the browser.

Ajax happens "behind the scenes", so it wouldn't output to your browser, you'd have it in your `success` handler's `response` argument.

if you want to test it just hit the url directly with your browser.

```
http://ciroot/index.php/publishlinks/check_links?matchesJSON=test%20text
```

***Also***, you can monitor all of your AJAX requests / responses with the Browser extension [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), very useful in situations like this.

Comment: You can check use firebug/chrome dev tools to see the AJAX response.

Comment: Thanks, chrome dev tools just became an official part of my workspace :)

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be a problem with your ajax call, not with codeigniter

start with removing `dataType: 'json'` - jQuery will find type of content itself as it's not json

and you need to output response in your function:

```
function(response) { window.alert(response) }
```